# CreateFileAsync in SuspensionManager throws indecipherable exception

Tags: windows-8, suspend

I created a new Windows Store app project using the Grid App (XAML) template. I ran the project (in debug mode) without changing a single line of code. While it was running, I switched back to Visual Studio and clicked the `Suspend` button in the toolbar.

At this point, the app threw a SuspensionManagerException. The exception’s details weren’t too helpful. The message is `SuspensionManager failed`. It has the (so far) unhelpful HResult `-2146233088`. It also has an InnerException that’s just as unhelpful. Its message is `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` and its HResult, which is `-2147467259`, is even worse than the outer exception’s HResult.

The line of code that throws the exception is in the `SuspensionManager`, which, again, is part of the project template. Here’s the line:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(sessionStateFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

The part that triggers the exception is `LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(…)`. The MSDN documentation for the CreateFileAsync method has a “Remarks” section that reads: `If you try to create a file in a virtual folder like a library or a file group, this method may fail.`

That’s it. There’s no explanation of why it may fail, or a description of the conditions under which it may fail, or what you can do about it.

As it happens, even when it fails, the file is actually created. The file in question is called `_sessionState.xml` and is located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<package_id>\LocalState`. If I delete the file and re-suspend the app, the exception is throw again and the file is recreated.

I've searched high and low and haven't found anything conclusive. The CreateFileAsync method is a projection, so I can't easily disassemble it or figure out why it "may fail".

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this problem, or how to go about debugging or solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that [`Frame.Navigate` should only take primitives as its `parameter` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx).

Also, make sure you are calling `GetDeferral` in your `async` event handler.

Comment: Note that I created a new project from the Grid App project template and ran it right away without changing a single line of code. The template code passes strings to `Navigate()`. And The `OnSuspending` handler acquires a deferral. To clarify: this is all MS code - I changed NOTHING.